# how could we echo 'a' with it's value 1 with function array_key_first in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

On php.net the manual for the [function.array-key-first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) shows the exemple below.

```
<?php
    $array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];
    
    $firstKey = array_key_first($array);
    
    var_dump($firstKey);
    ?>
The above example will output:

string(1) "a"
```

What I want to know is how could we echo 'a' with it's value 1. The output would be a1.

As I was writing this I actually found a way to do it, however I can't find anything explaining why it works. Could someone explain to me why it works and if it's valid?

```
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];

$firstKey = array_key_first($array);

echo array_key_first($array);
echo $array[array_key_first($array)];
?> 

Result for 8.1.10:
a1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works, the generally it's "valid" (which can be a bit of a subjective term), unless it shows up a security problem or something like that. But that definitely isn't an issue here.

Anyway it's relatively simple:

[array_key_first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) returns the first key in the array, which of course is `a`.

So your code outputs `a` because you `echo` what `array_key_first($array);` returns.
Then your code outputs `1` because you told it to get the value from the array at the key `a`. `$array[array_key_first($array)]` is the equivalent of writing `$array["a"]` because, again, `array_key_first($array)` returns `a`.

I hope this makes sense.

P.S. Your `$firstKey = array_key_first($array);` is actually redundant because you never use the $firstKey value you generated. But it could have a purpose - to save repeated calls to array_key_first, you could have written the code like this instead:

```
$firstKey = array_key_first($array);
echo $firstKey;
echo $array[$firstKey];
```